# VBA code to find string in column then split the string in an offset location by space

Tags: excel, vba

So I want to Find all instances of a string then offset by going down two rows. Whatever is the 2 row offset I want to split by space into different columns. What I have right now is giving me an endless loop

```
Sub search()

Dim c As Range
Dim g As Range

With Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
Set c = .Find("PART", LookIn:=xlValues)
Set g = c.Offset(2, 0)

If Not c Is Nothing Then
    Do
        g.Value = Split(g, " ")
        Set g = c
        Set c = .FindNext(c)
        
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note, but `Set g = c.Offset(2, 0)` should be inside the loop, and `Set g = c` is unnecessary.

Comment: What do you want doing with the split cell? Would you use only the first resulting array element? Would you fill another cell with the second one (or more if more spaces exist)?

Comment: @BigBen that still causes an infinite loop

Comment: Yes, it was a side note, you need to also compare the address of each found cell vs the address of the original cell (see the answer).

Comment: @FaneDuru I want whatever is in the cell to be split into different columns in that same row. So if the cell A9 has [1 2 3 4 5] then I want A9 cell to be just 1, B9 cell to be just 2, C9 cell to be just 3, D9 to be 4, and E9 to be 5

Comment: Then, test my posted code, please. Now I must leave the office. The code is not tested. If some problems, I will solve them when I will be at home...

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub search()
 Dim c As Range, firstOne As String, arr As Variant

 With Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
    Set c = .Find("PART", LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstOne = c.Address
        Do
            firstOne = c.Address
            arr = Split(c.Offset(2, 0).Value, " ")
            If UBound(arr) <> -1 Then
                c.Offset(2, 1).Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
            Else
                c.Offset(2, 1).Value = "Empty cell"
                c.Offset(2, 0).Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstOne
    End If
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It gives an error but thanks for looking at it! I'll keep working on it

Comment: I am driving now... what error and where? If at splitting on rows, try 'Resize(1, existing...)'... 1 instead of nothing.

Comment: Yea it is at resizing and it giving an application/object-defined error with or without the 1 added

Comment: @aMoncy : The problem was not of the code itself... When the Offset cell is empty, the obtained array has `Ubound(arr) = -1` and `Resize(, 0)` returns an error. I updated the code to check this aspect and, in such a case, its interior will be green colored and it will write in the next column "Empty cell". Please, refresh the page (this one) and check the updated code.

Comment: @aMoncy : Still testing? Some feedback did not kill anybody... :)

Comment: ok so I got a chance to try it out today but this is giving an endless loop

Comment: @aMoncy: I tested the above code and it works well... That's why I am afraid that the problem should be in the sheet to be processed. So, if nothing confidential in your workbook, can you share it here using a transfer site? I am sure I will find a working solution for your specific situation. [Here](https://easyupload.io/) you can do it easily...